# Pivot Table - Max() in Combination with Case

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot, case

I've got the following query:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(ID_FK_Group) 
                    from [randomDb].[dbo].[table_GroupMembership]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT [UserDisplayName], ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select u.DisplayName as [UserDisplayName], gm.ID_FK_Group as [ID_FK_Group], gm.ModDate as [ModDate]
                from [randomDb].[dbo].[table_user] u
                join [randomDb].[dbo].[table_GroupMembership] gm on u.id_pk_user = gm.id_fk_user
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                MAX(CASE when [ID_FK_Group] != null THEN "x" ELSE " " END)
                for [ID_FK_Group] in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

If I use `MAX([ModDate])` instead of `MAX(CASE when [ID_FK_Group] != null THEN "x" ELSE " " END)` it works just fine but of course it then displays the moddate instead of a "x" in the pivot table.

I've tried using different combinations of the `case` statement in combination with `MAX()` but for some reason I always end up with the same error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you can't pivot over a `CASE` statement, so you'll have to move the expression out into the query, something like;

```
SELECT [UserDisplayName], ' + @cols + ' from 
(
    select u.DisplayName as [UserDisplayName], gm.ID_FK_Group as [ID_FK_Group],
      CASE when [ID_FK_Group] is not null THEN 'x' ELSE ' ' END tmp
    from [randomDb].[dbo].[table_user] u
    join [randomDb].[dbo].[table_GroupMembership] gm on u.id_pk_user = gm.id_fk_user
) x
pivot 
(
    MAX(tmp)
    for [ID_FK_Group] in (' + @cols + ')
) p
```

Comment: So it isn't the syntax, good to know. I will try your solution with the fixed expression tomorrow - thanks!

Comment: It doesn't exactly work like the way you posted it but the general idea seems to be right -  now it's up to me to implement it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect syntax, when dealing with null values you should use **IS NULL** and **IS NOT NULL** , also you should use only one apostrophe and not two when using string values.

Change your case part to this:

```
MAX(CASE when [ID_FK_Group] is not null THEN 'x' ELSE ' ' END)
```

You can read about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp)

Comment: That's all well and good, but that's not a _syntax_ error, the error is on the `CASE` part.

Comment: The case syntax itself is correct, I've updated my answer to relate to the string part as well.. thats what you meantr right? @JoachimIsaksson

Comment: The `CASE` syntax is correct, the problem seems to be though that you can't pivot over a case statement at all.

Comment: I hope you did realise @query variable is a string literal and I very much doubt that you can use nested single quotes. Furthermore as Joachim pointed out, the problem seems not to be within the syntax but more due to the fact that you apperently can't use a case statement in a pivot.